# UserPress for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wiki

I use plugin UserPress for WordPress in my site with Advanced Custom Fields.
I don't understand how i can insert in front-end wiki's forms Custom fields for registered users.

The docs for UserPress is very poor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link which explain how to add Acf in front end form : http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Make sure that you used the good version of tutorial [acf_form](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/) ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was what i need. All works greate